# jQuery UI Dialog does not display after page scrolled in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have a link:

```
<a class="fg-button ui-state-default fg-button-icon-left assistButton" pbcType="download" title="Click for download information"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span>File</a>
```

And I have some jQuery:

```
$(".assistButton").click(function(){
        $('#dialog').css('color', '#000000');
        $("#dialog").dialog({ 
            bgiframe: true,
            position: 'center',
            width: $(window).width()-80,
            height: $(window).height()-80,
            title: 'Some title',
            modal: true,
            buttons: { "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("destroy"); }}
        });
})
```

This works (the dialog opens properly) until you scroll down the screen.  Once you scroll down the screen the dialog does not appear, the screen does go gray since it is a modal dialog.

I was under the assumption that

```
position: 'center',
```

would center it in the screen but I guess it's centered left to right, not top to bottom...?

When in IE it works fine, when in firefox on Windows or OS X it does not work.

What am I missing?  I've found a few others (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4539 as an example),  around the web but nothing has worked so far.

Edit:
In firefox it opens but it is "above the fold" and I cannot scroll up to it.  It's there, I just can't see it.

Comment: Are you saying that the dialog does not pop open *at all* when you scroll down, or that it pops up but is "off screen" above the current scroll point?

Comment: Also, that's sort-of an odd way to make the dialog work. What I've always seen (and done) is that you call `.dialog()` once to set up the dialog, and then you call `$('#dlg').dialog("open")` when you want to open it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you there but I'm doing it this way since I use the same dialog for multiple purposes on the same screen so the title and content changes.  I would be interested in an example of how you do it if you have one...

Comment: That is an acceptable way to call the dialog. The other way that pointy is referring to is to call your `.dialog` outside of your click handler with all of the options specified and include `autoOpen: false`. Then inside the `click()` handler you simply call `$(selector).dialog("open")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery UI 1.8.3 or 1.8.4 (due to a mis-build 1.8.3 == 1.8.4) release](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/08/jquery-ui-1-8-4/) made some changes in this department, most notably this one:

> **DIALOG**
>   The dialog plugin has also been updated to allow full usage of the [position](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position) utility. Setting the dialog’s position with a string or array is still possible, but will be removed in a future version.

The positioning was overhauled to use the base position utility shared amongst the widgets so the code to handle things like a scrolled page is handled much more cleanly now.  In the one problem page we had with your bug, the 1.8.4 release fixed it.

Comment: Just downloaded it - about to test it out now.

Comment: After a little fussing around I got it to work.  I ended up setting position to specific x & y values.  Thanks for the help.